How to use cookies between Next.js client and Next.js server in a local development environment?
I’ve recently started studying Next.js and am working on a project using it. I apologize in advance if my knowledge is lacking.
I’m currently developing in a Next.js Pages Router environment. The frontend is running locally over HTTPS, while the backend API is deployed on a server. When a user successfully login, the backend sets cookies with the following attributes:

SameSite = None
Secure = true
HttpOnly = true
Domain = .example.com

In this case, cookies are correctly sent and included in requests from the Next.js client to the backend server because the cookie domain is set to .example.com, which matches the backend server's domain service.example.com.
However, cookies are not included when making requests from the Next.js client to the Next.js server due to the domain mismatch. As a result, the Next.js server cannot use these cookies when forwarding requests to the backend server.
In a production environment, I can ensure domain consistency to resolve this. But I would like to achieve the same behavior in my local development environment.
Additional Context:

After a successful login on the /signin page, I receive the set-cookie response from the backend server.
Then, I redirect the user to the /dashboard page. When redirected to the /dashboard page, the Next.js client requests the page from the Next.js server, and I want the cookie to be included in this request.
On the /dashboard page, I want to use getServerSideProps to fetch data, utilizing the cookie set by the server during login.
The issue seems to be that since the cookie domain is set to .example.com, the Next.js client does not attach the cookie when making requests to the Next.js server (localhost:3000).

Summary:
The frontend is running locally over HTTPS, and the backend server (service.example.com) is deployed. I want to include the cookies set by the backend server in requests from the Next.js client to the Next.js server. The reason for this is to use the cookies in getServerSideProps to fetch data.
Attempted Solution:
In the login logic, I check if the environment is local. If so, I would re-set the cookies with the domain set to localhost, allowing them to be used in communication between the Next.js client and the Next.js server.
Problem:
When tokens expire, the backend sends a new set-cookie response, and synchronizing these cookies between the local environment and the production logic seems complicated. I’m looking for a better solution before proceeding with this approach.
